# how to pass value from inputtext in foreach loop JSF

Tags: jsf, binding, jstl

I have concluded that the function cannot be called if I place the h:form within the foreach loop.

If I place the form outside and the button outside the foreach it will call the correct function. But how do I get desired result with one button for each row where i can pass the input text as a new value to the function?

Note that the getSeriesForPlayerIInfo works as it should

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="#{serviceSeries.getSeriesForPlayerInfo(club.name, player.stringID, aSerie, calendarBean)}">
            <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="   #{list[0] }" />
            <h:outputText value="   #{list[1] }" />
            <h:outputText value="#{serie.getSerieDateString(list[2]) }" />
            <h:outputText value="#{list[3]}"/>
            <h:outputText value="   #{list[4] }" />
            <h:outputText value="   #{list[5] }" />
            <h:outputText value="   #{list[6] }" />
            <h:inputText value="   #{list[7] }" />
            <h:outputText value="   #{list[8] }" />


            <h:commandButton action="#{serviceSeries.PlayerSerie}" value="Uppdatera">
            </h:commandButton>  
            </h:form>
            </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `<c:forEach>` with `<h:dataTable>` as I suggested on your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115470/page-calling-same-function-twice-jsf#comment31771081_21115470)? Plus you *need* a `<h:form>` around anything that updates a value/causes an action.

Comment: Would that really change the problem with the binding only containing one value ?

Comment: Why do you bind the input component to the view to later on just pass its value as a parameter? Just pass `list[7]` as the second parameter! By the way, it's not necessary to explicitly call the `toString()` method in EL, as it's called by the framework to display the current object value.

Comment: Still having problems getting the method call to work. Is there something wrong in the action parameter?

Comment: It will not work sending in list[7] since if I update the text field it will not carry over to list[7] it will just pass the original value

Answer (score 0):

In this construct, the `<c:forEach>` runs during view build time producing the JSF component tree. In effects, you end up with physically multiple `<h:inputText>` components in JSF component tree, each with the **same** binding:

```
<h:inputText ... binding="#{serieScore}" />
<h:inputText ... binding="#{serieScore}" />
<h:inputText ... binding="#{serieScore}" />
...
```

This is not right! You're binding physically different components to one and same bean property, hereby causing a messed up view state shared between all those components.

Get rid of `binding` altogether. It's the wrong tool for the job anyway. You should be using the `value` attribute the right way in order to get/set a value.

```
<h:inputText value="#{list[7]}" />
```

Supply if necessary a `Converter` if it's not a standard type like `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, etc.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)
- [What is component binding in JSF? When it is preferred to be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506679/what-is-component-binding-in-jsf-when-it-is-preferred-to-be-used/)

Comment: What you are saying is that I should have a class that emulates the output from the "select xxx from" ? So i could set the list[7] which is impossible as it is now. Since it seems to be read only.

Comment: It's not read only. I'd work on figuring and fixing the "it seems" part.

Comment: Probably true that it's not read only. But it's always getting the original value and not the one set by the input field.